# MySQL Where date is not equal to current year

Tags: mysql, date, syntax

I have this syntax here:

```
date_record != YEAR(CURDATE())
```

and all the record returned are have the year 2013...What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What sort of data type is `date_record`?

Answer (score 2):

maybe just compare the years...

```
YEAR(date_record) != YEAR(CURDATE())
```

Comment: that returns nothing, I even tried the other way = instead of != and nothing, I am using phpmyadmin

Comment: have you tried the extract function? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract